# Publishing journals in mathematics.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving, publishing

I want to ask if I am to publish any research paper on trigonometric function. Where is the best place to do that and what field of mathematics can it be categorized?

Comment: You may want to try asking this question on the Academia stackexchange.

Comment: What is your result about , and do you think it is something no one has came up with before ?

Comment: Please do not edit the question to remove all its content once it has been answered (even if it has been put on hold).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what's in the paper, you might try [The College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal#AuthorInformation).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Mathematics section of arXiv.
You can find it at:
http://arxiv.org/

Others mentioned that it would "hurt your resume" if you published something "trivial". I believe the only way that can happen is if you publish in a very poor quality journal, and/or pay to have your work published. Don't do that!

A good quality journal will not accept a paper that is trivial, and that is your best chance for good standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have found something new concerning trigonometric functions there are a number of online publishers, some free. From your post though one cannot tell what exactly you desire to publish (content is everything). I wouldn't recommend trying to publish anything without first finding either an application or a good reason for the paper. Moreover, publishing trivial matters could actually hurt your resume. ArXiv is a good site to have your paper peer reviewed before going for more formal publishing.

Comment: Can you tell me some examples of that online publisher.

Comment: What do you mean by trivial matters.

Comment: ArXiv is a good site to have your paper peer reviewed before going for more formal publishing

Comment: Trivial matters are things easily proven from existing theorems that do not have a significant effect on the mathematical landscape. Generally one publishes first in college, unless the person is quite gifted.

Comment: None the less , if you are a high school student or young university student , even the proof of something trivial could be rather impressive especially if it is the form of something not done before etc

Comment: @Quality of course! An elusive proof of something trivial can still be great, although, as I mention above, usually the problem must have some significance. If nothing else it might impress others, although a high quality journal won't publish anything trivial anyway unless you find some new proof of it. I don't mean to be discouraging... Ramanujan was a great example of greatness out of nothing in youth. Just trying to gauge the OP off of their post